# Evaluation of formula reduces domain and FullSimplify is wrong

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, summation

I would like a closed form for the formula
`Sum[Binomial[k - b, n] Binomial[n + b, a], {n, 0, k}]` where variables `k, a, b` are supposed to be integers. Simply evaluating this formula returns

```
Binomial[b, a] Hypergeometric2F1[1 + b, b - k, 1 - a + b, -1] -
    Binomial[-b + k, 1 + k] Binomial[1 + b + k, a] HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1 + b, 2 + b + k}, {2 + k, 2 - a + b + k}, -1]
```

which works fine when `a <= b` but returns `Indeterminate` when `b < a` even though the original formula doesn't. For example:

```
Unevaluated@
  Sum[Binomial[k - b, n] Binomial[n + b, a], {n, 0, k}] /. {k -> 6, a -> 2, b -> 1}
  (* 160 *)
```

while

```
Sum[Binomial[k - b, n] Binomial[n + b, a], {n, 0, k}] /. {k -> 6, a -> 2, b -> 1}
   (* Indeterminate *)
```

However, the evaluated formula does give the right answer in the `Limit`.

Additionally, `FullSimplify` even returns `0` under the assumption that `b < a`:

```
FullSimplify[
 Unevaluated@Sum[Binomial[k - b, n] Binomial[n + b, a], {n, 0, k}], 
 Element[k | a | b, Integers] && k >= 0 && 0 <= a <= k && 0 <= b < a]
   (* 0 *)
```

So my question is: is this a bug? Is there a way to get Mathematica to try to simplify the sum over the whole domain?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, the formula as returned by *Mathematica* does have the blemish you describe, due to the hypergeometric functions becoming infinite. This is actually a common problem encountered by people who use `Sum[]` to evaluate sums involving binomial coefficients. However, at least for this case, by using the [Olver hypergeometric function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.1.E2) instead (or what *Mathematica* calls `Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[]`), we can convert that result into something more useful. To wit,

```
(b! Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1 + b, b - k, 1 - a + b, -1] +
 b Binomial[k - b, k] k! (b + k + 1)!
 HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 1 + b, 2 + b + k}, {2 + k, 2 - a + b + k}, -1])/a!
```

is an expression equivalent to the one produced by `Sum[]` but (AFAICT) does not suffer indeterminacy problems.